# Reaction stoichiometry for calculation of Kp

Tags: equilibrium, stoichiometry, pressure

> NH$_2$CO$_2$NH$_4$(s)⇌$2$ NH$_3$(g)+ CO$_2$(g)

I want to calculate K$_p$ for the reaction above, given that the total pressure is $0.63$ bar.

My calculations:

$0.63$ = p(CO$_2$) + p(NH$_3$)
,   where p(NH$_3$) = $1/2$ p(CO$_2$) (For every NH$_3$ half a CO$_2$ is needed)

$0.63$ = p(CO$_2$) + ($1/2$ p(CO$_2$) = $3/2$p(CO$_2$) -> p(CO$_2$) = $0.42$ bar , p(NH$_3$) = $0.21$ bar

So, K$_p$ = ($0.21$)$^2$ * ($0.42$) = $0.0185$ bar$^3$

**However**, the answer key's way of calculating this is:

$0.63$ = p(CO$_2$) + p(NH$_3$)
,   where p(NH$_3$) = $2$ p(CO$_2$)

$0.63$ = $3$p(CO$_2$) , so that  p(CO$_2$) = $0.21$ bar and p(NH$_3$) = $0.42$ bar

How can p(NH$_3$) = $2$ p(CO$_2$)? Isn't that wrong? Or am I thinking wrong? I have contacted my professor but haven't received an answer yet and our exam is tomorrow so hopefully someone here can help me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time one molecule of salt is decomposed, it produced $\ce{2 NH3}$ for $\ce{1 CO2}$. The number of molecules $\ce{NH3}$ is always double from that of $\ce{CO2}$ in the gas phase. Now the partial pressure of a given compound is proportional to the number of molecules of this compound in the gas phase. As a consequence, the partial pressure of $\ce{NH3}$ is always twice as high as the partial pressure of $\ce{CO2}$